# WGS84 conversion to EPSG:3067

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, openlayers-2, proj, epsg

I'm trying to convert coordinates from WGS84 to EPSG:3067 with proj4js and Openlayers, but can't get the conversion right. When I run `proj4('EPSG:3067',[-24.9993393, -60.184716]);` it gives 
`[-2143537.623518457, -7831430.649243464]`
When clicked on the map the point of coordinates it gives
`[-2182546.021603215, -12759115.371540245]` which is accurate if I put the center of the map to the clicked coordinates. Below is the code where the EPSG:3067 is defined.

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3067", "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");
extent = [-3670733.46, 4601971.85, 642319.78, 9362767.00];
ol.proj.get('EPSG:3067').setExtent(extent);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the degree coordinates should be in Helsinki (for which UTM zone 35 is correct),

you should enter `24.9993393, 60.184716`. Note that proj expects East - North order, with negative singns for Southern and western coodinates.

Converted to EPSG:3067, the coordinates are `389042, 6673664`.

Comment: Yeah, the coordinates should be in Helsinki and I got now same result as you. I think the problem is with my map with uses EPSG:3067.
http://pastebin.com/szxi09rA
Now the center of map is like 1000km north. Something like `28.2064459, 68.7603119` WGS84